# Expressão regular pra validar urls

Tags: regex

Tenho um Web Crawler que pega links de sites,mas ele captura muitos links que não preciso.

Queria uma expressão regular que filtre os link encontrados.E somente os links como esses passariam.

http://idgnow.com.br/internet/2017/07/12/em-queda-acoes-da-snap-ficam-abaixo-do-preco-do-ipo-pela-primeira-vez/

http://exame.abril.com.br/tecnologia/itau-usara-inteligencia-artificial-para-ter-agencias-mais-seguras/

Comment: Acredito que isso não seja possivel. Você possui algum padrão sobre os links? Quais você não gostaria que fossem exibidos?

Comment: Gostaria que urls que contenham ?# e outros caracteres não fossem capturadas.

Comment: Jeferson, aqui as pessoas estao para te ajudar a resolver um problema e não para fazer algo de graça pra você. Então coloque o código que você esta escrevendo e tira suas duvidas referente a ele.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem alguns meios de fazer isso que você falou na pergunta, você pode capturar somente os *links* que não possuem os caracteres que você mencionou (`!#`) ou ignorar o link caso o caractere que você deseja seja capturado.

Como não conheço o funcionamento da sua aplicação vou deixar os 2 jeitos aqui e como você não mencionou o *flavour* da **RegEx** nem a linguagem que ela sera usada vou assumir que seja algo parecida com o *flavour* `pcre`(php).

Caso você queira identificar as cadeias de caracteres que **POSSUAM** `#` ou `!` use esse padrão:

```
(?=.*#|.*!)(.*)
```

Para obter o resultado que você deseja, você deve identificar todos os `matchs` dessa expressão e desconsidera-los, aqui tem um [teste](https://regex101.com/r/fPwk43/1) que fiz para visualizar melhor o resultado.

Caso você queira identificar as cadeias de caracteres que **NÃO POSSUAM** o padrão:

```
((?!=.*#|.*!)(.*))
```

Nesse caso você deve considerar **somente** os `matchs` e desconsiderar as cadeias que não foram capturadas, aqui outro [teste](https://regex101.com/r/fPwk43/2) mas com essa expressão.

**Explicação:**

As duas regex funcionam de forma semelhante, porém em uma é utilizado um ***positive*** lookahead (`?=`) e na outra o ***negative*** lookahead (`?!=`).
O lookahead é um token que faz uma analise da cadeia de caracteres e só retorna se houver ou não um padrão específico.
Depois disso existe a cadeia que determinará a condição para o lookahead (`.*#|.*!`), ela indica que haverá uma cadeia de caracteres que podem ser números letras ou símbolos e depois disso `#` ou `!`.

No fim existe (`.*`) que capturará todos os caracteres (caso for o positive lookahead) ou não (caso for o negative lookahead).