# Validação de URL regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Boa tarde. Eu preciso fazer uma validação de URL usando javascript. Eu tenho a seguinte regex:

```
/^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@@!\$&'\ 
(\)\*\+,;=.]+$/gm
```

Acontece que se eu digitar por exemplo: *www.teste* ela valida. O que eu precisava era que fosse validado também .com, .br, ou qualquer outra extensão com no mínimo 2 caracteres. Como posso adicionar isso na minha regex?

Comment: [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8667070) tem várias opções, e veja que é uma regex mais complicada que outra, já que validar URL com regex [não é tão simples assim](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex). De qualquer forma, eu tiraria o segundo ponto do trecho `(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+` (ficando apenas `(?:\.[\w\-]+)+`, ou ainda `(?:\.\w+)+`, senão a regex vai aceitar vários pontos seguidos, [veja](https://regex101.com/r/zYD81N/1/) (não vi se tem mais coisas pra arrumar)

Comment: Apenas por curiosidade, e se a pessoa tiver um dominio com final `.io`, ou então um dominio com final `.eu`?

Comment: A questão é que `www.teste` é uma URL válida conforme a RFC 3986, assim como `teste`, `/home`, `john@due`, etc. Se não deseja validar esses valores, aconselho que você edite a pergunta e descreva exatamente quais seriam os valores válidos.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Expressão regular pra validar urls](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220638/express%c3%a3o-regular-pra-validar-urls)

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:?#[\]@@!\$&'\ 
(\)\*\+,;=.]+$
```

Basta tirar uma barra :D. Testa essa que mandei acima.

Eu sempre utilizo o site regex101.com para testar. Entra lá pra você ver como funciona, ele te mostra o que cada parte do seu regEx está fazendo separando por cores, é bem intuitivo.

Comment: Essa regex considera que `www.teste` é válido, então acho que não corrigiu o problema: https://regex101.com/r/0xIv1P/1/

Comment: mas se a pessoa digitar google.com, deve ser válido certo? ou deve ser obrigatório o www? @hkotsubo

Comment: Eu *acho* que google.com é válido, mas a pergunta diz que `www.teste` não é. De qualquer forma, a regex que está na pergunta já valida google.com - https://regex101.com/r/3KmlUd/1/

Comment: Essa regex está furada, validou `www.as!.com.!   ziriguidum.www.........1234@@@@@@@!!!####*())(+=-_;[]?`

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar essa expressão:

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?(w{3}\.)?[\w_-]+((\.\w{2,}){1,2})(\/([\w\._-]+\/?)*(\?[\w_-]+=[^\?\/&]*(\&[\w_-]+=[^\?\/&]*)*)?)?$
```

Você pode testar no link:
https://regex101.com/r/0xIv1P/2